# How do I use my Stack Exchange OpenID?

Tags: support, stack-exchange-openid

I'm trying to sign up for mrmoneymustache.com, but I'm not sure about where to find my Stack Exchange OpenID URL.

I entered https://openid.stackexchange.com/, but it did not work for me:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set Vanity OpenID (second field) by [editing your profile](https://openid.stackexchange.com/user/edit) (accepts "Only letters, numbers, periods, and dashes").

Then in [your profile](https://openid.stackexchange.com/user) copy the link going after "Vanity Id", and paste it where you were going to log in. I think it should work.

OR: click "Use your own URL to log in" and copy the link from the second tag.

Comment: // , Both links 404. They show up as "https://openid.stackexchange.com/user". Must I edit them to make them work?

Comment: @Nathan nonono, you should login https://openid.stackexchange.com/account/login first, and then the links become available.

Comment: // , Ah. can I edit your answer to explain that?